# Python = in DEF

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

Code:

```
print("Starting...")

def test():
    notare = input()
    bote()

def bote():
    if notare == "a":
        print("b")
    else:
        print("c")

test()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 5, in test
    bote()
  File "test.py", line 8, in bote
    if notare == "a":
NameError: name 'notare' is not defined
```

Comment: Correct; `notare` is not defined. Is your question *why* it is not defined, or do you want some workaround so that it *is* defined in `bote`?

Comment: The problem is that you have not defined what `notare` is in your `bote` function. You need to pass it as a variable to bote. Also, this is a very basic question and shows no effort on your part. Just pasting your code and error message won't make people very happy to help you..

Answer (score 0):

python wont know the function exists... 
Python executes in a orderly fashion... Meaning you have to declare the function before you can call it...

So to your problem.. 
Try moving the function above the function calling it..

Like so

```
print("Starting...")

def bote(notare):
    if notare == "a":
        print("b")
    else:
        print("c")

def test():
    notare = input()
    bote(notare)


test()
```